# Lebesgue density of a sum of i.i.d. exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$, i.e., its Lebesgue density is given by

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{- \lambda x} & \text{if} \quad x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if} \quad x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
The characteristic function of $X$ can be then computed through
$$
\varphi(z) = E[e^{izX}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{izx} \lambda e^{ - \lambda x} d x = \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{ (iz - \lambda)x} }{iz - \lambda } d ((iz - \lambda)x) = \lambda \frac{ e^{ (iz - \lambda) x} }{i z - \lambda} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda  - iz }
$$
If we further take $n$ i.i.d. copies of $X$, then the characterisitic function of their sum is given by
$$
\frac{ \lambda^n}{ {( \lambda - i z )}^n} \tag{1}
$$
Now, consider a somewhat reverse problem, namely, given the characteristic function in $(1)$, can one come up with a Lebesgue density? I would be interested in an explicit computation. Can [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) be helpful?

Comment: Look up: Gamma distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compute the density of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ directly by convolution. Assume that for some $n\geqslant 1$ that $$f_{S_n}(x) = \frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda x}. $$
Then
\begin{align}
f_{S_{n+1}}(x) &= f_{S_{n}}\star f_{X_{n+1}}(x)\\
&= \int_0^x \frac{\lambda(\lambda y)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda y} \lambda e^{-\lambda(x-y)}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x\lambda(\lambda y)^{n-1}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{(n-1)!}\left[\frac{(\lambda y)^n}n \right]_0^x\\
&= \frac{\lambda (\lambda x)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda x}.
\end{align}
By induction, we see that $f_{S_n} = \frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda x}$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be from $0$ to $\infty$? Also, isn't it supposed to be $dy$ instead of $dx$?

Comment: Sorry, the $\mathsf dx$ was a typo. The integral is from $0$ to $x$ because the convolution integral is
$$
f_{S_n}\star f_{X_{n+1}}(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f_{S_n}(y)f_{X_{n+1}}(x-y)\ \mathsf dy.
$$
Now remember $f_{S_n}$ includes a factor of $\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}$, as does $f_{X_{n+1}}$. So we have $0<y<\infty$ and $0<x-y<\infty$. These bounds yield $0<y<x$.

Comment: Thanks. I also realized, and as the comment to my question suggests, that the obtained characteristic function corresponds to $\Gamma(n, \lambda)$. So we can take the respective density.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible in general.

Here is a useful result that may work sometimes.

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a random vector with characteristic function $\phi$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} |\phi(t)| dt < \infty$$

Then $\mathbb{P}_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure with density function

$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \exp(-i \langle t,x \rangle) \phi(t)dt $$

Comment: Do you by chance know any book which contains this result?

Comment: Probably "Billingsley: measure and probability" but can be wrong!